# SqlServerCe file name not valid

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I am creating an add-in for outlook 2010, using VS 2010. I was looking around for a way to store data locally and I saw that a bunch of people were suggesting Sql CE. I tried it out and kept running into this error
File name is not valid: Data Source = |DataDirectory|\data.sdf

```
string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.dataConn;

        SqlCeConnection dbConn = new SqlCeConnection(conString);

        try
        {
            using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conString))
            {
                con.Open();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
```

I used the tutorial shown here:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlce

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

|DataDirectory| is a special variable in the connection string that is expanded at runtime. It is expanded as follows:

```
  - For applications placed in a directory on the user machine, this will be the app's (.exe) folder.
  - For apps running under ClickOnce, this will be a special data folder created by ClickOnce
  - For Web apps, this will be the App_Data folder
```

This is not working for your Outlook plugin. I am guessing the context it is running in doesn't set a value for it. You can try either providing a full path to the database in your connection string (replacing |DataDirectory|) or setting the value of the DataDirectory in the Application Domain dynamically using the following:

```
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", newpath)
```

Have a look at [Working with local databases](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smartclientdata/archive/2005/08/26/456886.aspx) for more information.